# How to automatically type the keys and values of a predefined object?

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I have a mapping object and a helper function to get the key from the value like this:

```
const map = {
    0: 'a',
    1: 'b',
    2: 'c',
    3: 'd',
}

function getKey(value: Value): Key {
    return Object.keys(map).find(key => map[key] === value);
}
```

Usually I have to type `Key` and `Value` manually like this:

```
type Key = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | '0' | '1' | '2' | '3'
type Value = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd'
```

Is there a way to avoid doing that? The idea is that the object can be changed, or even be a result of a function. The only thing can be sure is that the key is number and value is string, but I don't want to type it too generic. I understand the concept of generics but I don't know how to implement this.

Comment: (See previous comment) Also, your code can’t possibly produce numeric output since number keys are coerced to strings when used as object indexes, so the output of `getKey` will be a string. Could you [edit] the question to avoid this issue?  Unless you’re *asking* about key coercion it’s probably just a distraction from your question.

Comment: *Which is more important to you? Known narrow types or changeable unknown values?* — in my understanding Dimava's answer achieve both, right? Also, I guess I can always wrap the output in a `parseInt()` function to convert it to number?

Comment: hmm. Take a look at `at const` I get that it is to restrict the object to readonly, which is my intention. I mean the object will be created manually or via a function from other manually created objects, then stay intact. By changing I mean that the data of the objects can be changed by hand. I just need to type to be independent of the value of the data, which their answer seems to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `as const` clause and reverse the object like this:
https://tsplay.dev/mbaX2N
Do you need a case for non-PropertyKey(string|number) values?

```
const map = {
  0: 'a',
  1: 'b',
  2: 'c',
  3: 'd',
} as const
// ^^^^^^^
// const map: {
//     readonly 0: "a";
//     readonly 1: "b";
//     readonly 2: "c";
//     readonly 3: "d";
// }

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]
type MapKey = keyof typeof map;
//   ^?
// type MapKey = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3
type MapValue = ValueOf<typeof map>
//   ^?
// type MapValue = "a" | "b" | "c" | "d"


type Reverse<T extends Record<PropertyKey, PropertyKey>> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K]]: K
}
type ReversedMap = Reverse<typeof map>
// type ReversedMap = {
//     readonly a: 0;
//     readonly b: 1;
//     readonly c: 2;
//     readonly d: 3;
// }

function getKey<V extends ValueOf<typeof map>>(value: V): ReversedMap[V] {
  return Object.entries(map).find(([k, v]) => v === value)![0] as any
}

let a = getKey('a')
//  ^?
// let a: 0
```

Comment: Does this really ever output numbers? Don’t numeric keys get coerced to strings and stay that way when iterating the object?

Comment: @jcalz you are right actually, need to cast to `${key}` I guess

Comment: what does the `//   ^?` do?

Comment: @Ooker https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Orta.vscode-twoslash-queries (works in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play )

Comment: how do I restrict `MapKey` to `'0' | '1' | '2' | '3'`?

Comment: @Ooker by `keyof typeof` of `as const`

Comment: you mean `type MapKey = keyof typeof map as const`?

Comment: I mean `const map = {...} as const` and `type MapKey = keyof typeof map`

Comment: Or do you want `const map = {...} as const satisfies Record<0|1|2|3, string>` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254822/discussion-between-ooker-and-dimava).